# Read delivery logs of AWS Text messaging (SMS) from Kinesis stream

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, amazon-kinesis

I'm using AWS SNS SMS feature and send sms to the Phone. I want to read delivery status success|failed.
For that i'm following the below steps:

- Create Cloudwatch logs group.
- Create Kinesis subscription filter.
- Now log will be available on Kinesis steam.

I'm able to read logs from Kinesis steam but not in required format, i want it in json format.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbGD6.png)

If i'm send direct data to Kinesis stream and reading back it work fine and properly readable format(json).

**Delivery logs:**

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageId": "0aaabb6c-35ab-5a0e-b446-e1048f5623b9",
        "timestamp": "2022-01-24 14:33:33.441"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "destination": "<phone-number>",
        "smsType": "Transactional",
        "providerResponse": "Sandboxed account unable to send to number.",
        "dwellTimeMs": 44
    },
    "status": "FAILURE"
}
```

**Code:**
DeliveryStatusProcessor#processRecords(ProcessRecordsInput processRecordsInput)

```
public void processRecords(ProcessRecordsInput processRecordsInput) {
        try {
            log.info("Processing {} record(s)", processRecordsInput.records().size());
        processRecordsInput.records().forEach(incomingDeliveryStatus ->
        {
            try {
                processRecord(incomingDeliveryStatus);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.info("Failed to process records.");
            }
        });
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        log.error("Caught throwable while processing records. Aborting.");
        Runtime.getRuntime().halt(1);
    } finally {
      //
    }
}

  private void processRecord(KinesisClientRecord record) throws IOException {
        byte[] messageStatus = new byte[record.data().remaining()];
        record.data().get(messageStatus);
        String string = new String(messageStatus);
        System.out.println("================>>>"+string);      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

cloudwatch sends logs in [gzip compressed format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html#:%7E:text=When%20log%20events%20are%20sent%20to%20the%20receiving%20service%2C%20they%20are%20base64%20encoded%20and%20compressed%20with%20the%20gzip%20format.). you need to decompress them in consumer application to get in correct format

Comment: Hey @Ajikya, it's working. Great help. Thanks a lot.